# Issues with Toggle

Tags: ui-design, axis, boolean

hope you're all good..

I'm struggling with a simple toggle for inverting Y axis..

What i have works for my first scene but i'm trying to keep this setting through all scenes, hence why the script below isn't destroyed on load..

Although its fine for the first scene and works, to help me debug it i'm trying to get its value to show up on the console - the InvertYCheck() function - but it displays the console text once but then doesn't update (display the new value) again even if i add an if statment in the Update() function.

So from this, is seems that it despite being able to check and uncheck the toggle in-game, the value of it will only update the first time you click it.

Basically, all i want is the user to be able to select the Y axis orientation during training (scene 1), then retain this value (but not the UI toggle) so that becomes the setting throughout the game..

From looking at the code it should work but it doesn't. Any ideas why not?

Thanks,

Paul..

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class InvertYscr : MonoBehaviour {

    public Toggle InvertYtog;
    public bool InvertY = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        InvertYtog = InvertYtog.GetComponent<Toggle> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    }

    void Awake () {
        DontDestroyOnLoad (this);
    }

    public void InvertYCheck(bool newVal)
    {
        InvertY = newVal;
        print ("Y Axis is: " + InvertY.ToString());
    }

    public float MouseYval (float MY) {
        if (InvertY) {
            MY = MY * 1;
        } else if (!InvertY) {
            MY = MY * -1;
        }
        return MY;
    }
}
```

Comment: Never mind, thanks anyway. Got it sorted now. I wasn't calling the function correctly from all scenes. Doh!

Answer (score -1):

Whether the player prefers the Y-axis inverted or not is a personal preference of the player, hence it's something which fits quite well into the [`PlayerPrefs`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) class. This is a persistent key/value store which doesn't just survive a scene reload but even a game restart.

To set a player preference:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("InvertY", 1);
```

To read the player's preference when your player-controller is started:

```
void Start () {
    InvertY = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("InvertY") == 1;
}
```

Note that using player preferences is not appropriate when you simply want to pass data between scenes (use either [`static`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) variables or store the data in a game-object with [`DontDestroyOnLoad`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) enabled) or for saving more than a few values, or for implementing savegames which are more than a handful of values (serialize your game-state to a file and write that).

Comment: Hey Philipp, I didn't know about PlayerPrefs, very useful by the sounds of it. I've already implemented my version now but i'm definitely going to be using that in the next one :)